# Generating an html link in CakePHP 2.2.1+?

Tags: html, cakephp, hyperlink, html-helper, cakephp-2.2

How can I easily generate an HTML link, using the `HtmlHelper` class in CakePHP 2.2.1?

Imagine I declared a route that routes `/finest-perfumes-ever-2012` to the `Perfumes/Index` Controller/Action.

I need this generated link to be:

```
somedomain.com/finest-perfumes-ever-2012  //Generate link HAS to obey Routes I've set.
```

Instead of:

```
somedomain.com/Perfumes/Index
```

The [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink) doesn't seem to do much of a good job explaining how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have missed out the `2012` by accident or your question is more complicated than my answer below. Assuming the `2012` doesn't matter:

Cake makes use of quite a nifty feature - [reverse routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html).

If you've set up everything correctly, the following should output what you want.

```
<?php
Router::connect(
    '/finest-perfumes-ever',
    array('controller' => 'perfumes', 'action' => 'index')
);

echo $this->Html->link('View Finest Perfumes!', array('controller'=>'perfumes', 
                                                         'action' => 'index'));
```

Providing your URL (when created using the HTML helper) has parameters that match the route exactly, the reverse routing will look up what you want the route to be, and output links accordingly.

If the `2012` is important you could probably get this working by passing parameters - there are some [examples here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action)

Comment: I forgot to add the 2012, I edited that in. Are you saying that I need to use this `Router::connect` on every single view I need to invoke this URL in?

Comment: the `Router::...` goes in your `app/Config/routes.php`. Then, anytime you create a link using the above, it will automatically be output as `finest-perfumes-ever`; if that makes sense?

Comment: It does but your answer doesn't make it clear where I should put that `Router::connect` code. Does it go into some route configuration file, or in the View itself?

Comment: it goes in app/config/routes.php.  This answer is the correct way to approach your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Define route configuration into your app/Config/routes.php at the last of all routing statements.

You can do the same by [passing an argument to the action](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action) and define it in your routes.php file.

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.